# Error while running DTS package: SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

could any one help me to resolve this issue.

I'm executing a DTS package on my system from SQL Server Enterprise Manager by connecting to the Database Server (Remote server).  The execution completes with the error message

"DTSStep_DTSDataPumpTask_1:Error at Destination for Row number . Errors encountered so far in this task:"

This process try to upload a txt file to the database.  The text file can contain some null values in the columns.

But the strange thing is, my collegues/from other systems, I could able to run the same packages. I really got stuck here why its not working on my PC.  Here is the environment I'm using.

Environment:
Operating System:  Windows XP Sp2 
SQL SErver:  SQL Server 2000 
MS SQL Enterprise Manager:  Version 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a column in this database that is set to not allow nulls?

See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/228933